# Datomic pull expression

Tags: clojure, datomic

I was reading about the Datomic pull syntax here:

http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html

And it explains under wildcard that a pattern like `[*]` will pull an entity and recursively pulls its entity attributes. Direct quote:

> The wildcard specification * pulls all attributes of an entity, and recursively pulls any component attributes:

```
;; pattern
[*]

;; result
{:release/name "The Concert for Bangla Desh",
 :release/artists [{:db/id 17592186049854}],
 :release/country {:db/id 17592186045504},
 :release/gid #uuid "f3bdff34-9a85-4adc-a014-922eef9cdaa5",
 :release/day 20,
 :release/status "Official",
 :release/month 12,
 :release/artistCredit "George Harrison",
 :db/id 17592186072003,
 :release/year 1971,
 :release/media
 [{:db/id 17592186072004,
   :medium/format {:db/id 17592186045741},
   :medium/position 1,
   :medium/trackCount 2,
   :medium/tracks
   [{:db/id 17592186072005,
     :track/duration 376000,
     :track/name "George Harrison / Ravi Shankar Introduction",
     :track/position 1,
     :track/artists [{:db/id 17592186048829} {:db/id 17592186049854}]}
    {:db/id 17592186072006,
     :track/duration 979000,
     :track/name "Bangla Dhun",
     :track/position 2,
     :track/artists [{:db/id 17592186048829}]}]}
  ...
  ]}
```

However, when I try this myself I only get `db/id` values for `ref` types. I have to basically call out any ref type in a more verbose way in the `pull` expression, with something like this:

```
[* {:content/type [:db/ident] :content/locales [:db/ident] :content/groups [*]}]
```

And that's not even actually the end of it, because `:content/groups` itself has `ref` types inside of it. Did the behavior of wildcarding change at some point and the docs are not up to date? Or am I doing something wrong? Is there a better (more concise) way to go about saying, "just recursively pull it all in"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard in a pull expression only populates component attributes. That is, attributes with `:db/isComponent true` in the schema.

Looking at the [mbrainz schema](https://github.com/Datomic/mbrainz-sample/blob/master/schema.edn), only `:release/media` and `:medium/tracks` are component attributes, so they would be the only ones populated with a `[*]` pull pattern.

If your data model includes hierarchal reference chains (i.e. `:person/friend` as a reference to any person, who may also have friends referenced), you can define [recursive pull patterns](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html#recursive-specifications) and specify their recursive depth (or use `...` for unbounded).

This topic is also discussed on the [Datomic Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/datomic/cYOv1H0XIPM/discussion), and includes a link to an example recursive pull pattern.

Comment: ok, is there any reason why I might choose to not use `:db/isComponent true`, if my intention is to get the whole thing pulled in each time?

Comment: So reading from here: http://blog.datomic.com/2013/06/component-entities.html it seems like components are to take care of sub-objects that don't exist on their own without the parent. Does it make sense to make an enum value have `:isComponent true`?

Comment: from what I can tell, all enums have the same `:db/id`, so if a record got retracted that `:db/id` would also get retracted. So it seems like its desirable to have enum values be `:db/isComponent true` because I don't want to manually specify every single enum on a pull expression, but on the other hand they're by definition shared across entities, and so not suitable for `:db/isComponent`. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct - component entities should be things that only exist as part of their parent.

Comment: so is there no easy way to "automatically" pull in refs for enum values? As an example, in a given component, I may have 4-5 enums in various places, and generally a `(pull ?c [*])` suffices, except for the enums which then create this really annoying and long pull expression. It almost (_almost_) makes me want to just stick strings in there and to heck with the enums.

Comment: This discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/KI-kbOsQQbU/2ZiLH8TmXdkJ provides additional details you might find helpful.